# Fabric Python Parallel execution : share a variable

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

I am working on a tool which use Fabric.

I use the execute function like that :

```
execute(my_function, a_shared_var, hosts=servers)
```

a_shared_var is modify in my_function.

All is ok when my_function is not run in Parallel mode, but with @parallel a_shared_var duplicate into differents forks and impossible to share the information.

Have you got any idea, how can I have a_shared_var between all my hosts and when is back to main a_shared_var must be up to date with all modifications ?

I am thinking about write into a file in my_function, because I have not other idea...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Using a multiprocessing Queue. 
Before running the execute function, I start a thread which have to read into the Queue.
And into my_function I have a producers which put messages into the Queue.

Comment: Do you have an example of this code? I'm trying to do the exact same thing!